# Why $ X_d $ is a complex variety with those assumptions?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Could someone explain to me please, why is, in the case of a subset $ X_{ f_{d}} $ of $ \mathbb{P}^n ( \mathbb{C} ) $ défined by $ X_{f_{d}} = \{ (x_0 : \dots : x_n ) \in \mathbb{P}^n ( \mathbb{C} ) \ | \ f_d ( x_0 , ... , x_n ) = 0 \ \} $ such that, $ f_d $ is an homogeneous polynomial of degree $ d $ : $ X_{f_{d}} $ is a complex variety, if and only if :

$$ \dfrac{ \partial f_{d} }{ \partial x_{0} } (x_0 , \dots , x_n ) = \dots = \dfrac{ \partial f_{d} }{ \partial x_{n} } (x_0 , \dots , x_n ) = 0 \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ x_0 = \dots = x_n = 0 $$

?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Presumably you left out the word "smooth"?

Comment: No. I don't think so.  :)

Comment: Well, then the statement is false ;).

Comment: $ \dfrac{ \partial f_{d} }{ \partial x_{0} } (x_0 , \dots , x_n ) = \dots = \dfrac{ \partial f_{d} }{ \partial x_{n} } (x_0 , \dots , x_n ) = 0 \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ x_0 = \dots = x_n = 0 $ or $ d f = 0 \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ x_0 = \dots = x_n = 0 $ means that the only singular point in $ X_d $ is $ (0, \dots , 0 ) $, no ?

Comment: ...well, that would be true in affine space. But $(0,0,\dots,0)$ isn't a point of projective space, so the conclusion there is that $X_{f_d}$ is actually smooth.

Comment: As indication, the author of my book says we have to consider the cone of $ \mathbb{C}^{n+1} $ of equation $ f_d $ that is a variety outside of the vertex. So, how to solve the problem by this indication ?

Comment: Is the book in French? Often "variété complexe" translates as "complex manifold" rather than "complex variety", which could explain the confusion here.

Comment: Yes. It's in French.  :) see here : www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/sabbah/hodge-str.pdf , page : $ 9 $.  :)